# RegEx works with kotlin but didn't work as expected with dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

The regex works fine in kotlin code:

```
var text = "Today, scientists confirmed the worst possible outcome: the massive asteroid will collide with Earth"
    
val encodeRegex = Regex("""'s|'t|'re|'ve|'m|'ll|'d| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+""")
    
   val x= encodeRegex.findAll(text).map { result ->
            result.value
        }
     
    print(x.toList())
```

The output:

```
    [Today, ,,  scientists,  confirmed,  the,  worst,  possible,  outcome, :,  the,  massive,  asteroid,  will,  collide,  with,  Earth]
```

I tried to use the same regexp with flutter but it doesn't work as expected.

Dart code:

```
    final RegExp encodeRegex = RegExp(
    r"""'s|'t|'re|'ve|'m|'ll|'d| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+""",
  );
  
  final text ='Today, scientists confirmed the worst possible outcome: the massive asteroid will collide with Earth';
  
  
  final tokens = encodeRegex
        .allMatches(text)
        .map(
          (element) =>
              element.group(0),
        )
        .toList();
  
  print('${tokens}');
```

The output:

```
[Today,,  scientists,  confirmed,  the,  worst,  , ossible,  outcome:,  the,  massive,  asteroid,  will,  collide,  with,  Earth]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by default the regular expression does not match unicode categories. You need to add , `unicode: true` for the regular expression to match them. Try:

```
    main(){
final RegExp encodeRegex = RegExp(
    r"""'s|'t|'re|'ve|'m|'ll|'d| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+""", unicode: true
  );
  
final text ='Today, scientists confirmed the worst possible outcome: the massive asteroid will collide with Earth';
  
  
final tokens = encodeRegex
        .allMatches(text)
        .map(
          (element) =>
              element.group(0),
        )
        .toList();
  
  print('${tokens}');
}
```

It works in DartPad.
If unicode is not enabled it matches `p{L}` and `p{N}` as literal pL and pN.